# Adding index to mysql dynamic column

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a select query which has a where clause: WHERE CONCAT(att.subjectId,'#',att.classId) IN ('132#100') . I have added a composite index on subjectId and classId but will these indexes be of any use for such a dynamic column. If not is it possible to create a column on a dynamic column like CONCAT(att.subjectId,'#',att.classId).

Comment: In short: no, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

Best I'm aware MySQL offers no means to create an index on an expression/function result.

The work around is to populate an extra field using triggers, and to index it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, functions are not the best idea for "where" clauses, they force dbms to do "full scan" which kills performance.

I think it's better to use few "(att.subjectId = '132' and att.classId = '100')" concatenated with "OR" (for each term in your "IN" list) and add some indexes for separated columns.